# Python: Concatenating sublists between different lists

Tags: python, list, loops, concatenation, list-comprehension

I have two lists of lists, of equal length, like this:

```
lstA = [[1,4,5,6],[4,5],[5,6],[],[],[],[],[]]
lstB = [[7,8],[4,5],[],[],[],[2,7,8],[7,8],[6,7]]
```

And I want to concatenate the sublists at each index position such that they make a single sublist, like this:

```
 newlst = [[1,4,5,6,7,8],[4,5],[5,6],[],[],[2,7,8],[7,8],[6,7]]
```

Ideally, the new sublists will remove duplicates (like in newlst[1]). I converted the integers to strings, and attempted this:

```
for i in range(len(lstA)):
    c = [item + item for item in strA[i], strB[i]]
```

but that adds each item from each list to itself before adding to the other list, resulting in something like this:

```
failedlst = [[["1","4","5","6","1","4","5","6"],["7","8","7","8"]],[["4","5","4","5"],["4","5","4","5"]]...etc]
```

And this still doesn't actually join the two sublists, just makes a new sublist of the two sublists. Any help would be greatly appeciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making a list by concatenating items in parallel is very simple, using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in combination with the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function.

```
newlst = [x+y for x,y in zip(lstA, lstB)]
```

If you want to remove duplicates, you can use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). If you then want to put the items back in order in a list, you can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

In combination, this:

```
newlst = [sorted(set(x+y)) for x,y in zip(lstA, lstB)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
lstA = [[1,4,5,6],[4,5],[5,6],[],[],[],[],[]]
lstB = [[7,8],[4,5],[],[],[],[2,7,8],[7,8],[6,7]]

answer = []
for idx in range(len(lstA)):
    answer.append(sorted(list(set(lstA[idx]+lstB[idx]))))

print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5], [5, 6], [], [], [2, 7, 8], [7, 8], [6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) and [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html) module.

```
In [94]: from itertools import chain

In [95]: lstA = [[1,4,5,6],[4,5],[5,6],[],[],[],[],[]]

In [96]: lstB = [[7,8],[4,5],[],[],[],[2,7,8],[7,8],[6,7]]

In [97]: [list(set(chain.from_iterable(item))) for item in zip(lstA, lstB)]
Out[97]: [[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5], [5, 6], [], [], [8, 2, 7], [8, 7], [6, 7]]
```

If you want to sort the sublist then:

```
In [98]: [sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(item))) for item in zip(lstA, lstB)]
Out[98]: [[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 4, 5, 5], [5, 6], [], [], [2, 7, 8], [7, 8], [6, 7]]
```